# JSON web tokens(JWT) implementation in Finagle stack

Tags: scala, jwt, finagle

Do we have a jwt service out there for finagle?

A sample implementation  would be great!

Answer (score 1):

This question will, probably, be closed, but to point you in the right direction, pretty much everybody uses `nimbus` library for JWT (look it up). There is nothing special about integrating it with finagle compared to any other framework: just implement a `SimpleFilter` that creates/validates the tokens in the header.

That's if you are using HTTP. For binary protocols, it is more complicated. I have implemented something like that, but it was ugly. Finagle thrift does not have the notion of `headers` per se, so you have to either create your own codec that would support it (you can use `ThriftServerFramedCodec` as an example), or use `Contexts.broadcast` to tag your tokens along with the requests (this is inferior to replacing the codec, because by the time your app gets to validate the token, the entire payload is already deserialized).